# Error downgrade grails 2.0.0.RC1

Tags: grails

I'm upgrading my application to Grails 2.0.0 RC3.

Now, I want to downgrade my application to Grails 2.0.0 RC1 but when I run it I have this error:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error

URI
    /directory/
Class
    java.lang.IllegalStateException
Message
    No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web
    request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually
    operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running
    outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or
    RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

Trace

   Line | Method
->> 886 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   908 | run     in     ''
^   662 | run . . in java.lang.Thread
```

I have no idea how to get rid of it.